# PhpStorm set all files / folders to brown background and weird structure

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

So I just noticed that my PhpStorm has set a background color to my project and also the structure is weird. All best explained by some screenshots.

This is how it is looking now, I cannot even see my `App` folder etc here:

[image]

After I click on `Project` in the top and then select `Project Files`, I can see my structure again like normal:

[image]

My question is, what does this mean and how can I set it "back to normal"? As for me, "normal" means the following:

[image]

I can see all my files in `Project` and also there is no brown background color.

What I have done so far, as suggested from Google searches, is:

1. Close the project, remove it from recent projects and opening it again in PhpStorm.
2. Removing the .idea folder and opening my project again.
3. Reload All From Disk.
4. Invalidate Caches.

P.S. This is a new Laravel project, with only some minor changes and all files added to git, and also just did one last commit. Nothing "fixes" this.

Comment: This "yellowish" background means that the IDE treats those files/folders as excluded or not part of the project (outside of the project). Can be caused by some broken/out-of-sync project config file. Usually deleting the `.idea` folder (**while IDE is closed**) and then reopening the project ("Open" and point to the project root folder -- the IDE will make a new project from existing files) is enough to fix it. What IDE version do you use? This kind of thing should have been fixed (or greatly improved) in the latest stable.

Comment: I have tried it again, deleting the `.idea` folder and it worked this time. Perhaps I did it while the IDE was open. Using latest stable version of Php Storm. Thanks, if you can add this as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This "yellowish" background means that the IDE treats those files/folders as excluded or not part of the project (i.e. outside of the project). This can be caused by some broken/out-of-sync project config file (for whatever reason, e.g. when making a project and there is incomplete `.idea` folder already / merge conflict etc).

Deleting `.idea` subfolder **while IDE is closed** and then reopening the project is enough to fix it (use "Open" and point to the project root folder and PhpStorm will make a new project from existing files).

Related forum thread/tickets:

- https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/4404912351506/comments/4404921897746
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-271728
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-296960

Answer (score 2):

I made a backup of the `.idea` folder when PHPStorm was closed, like the selected answer recommends, and then started PHPStorm. I then used Meld to track the differences in the 2 folders. In my case the `[project-name].iml` file was missing. Once I copied `[project-name].iml` from the new `.idea` to the original `.idea` everything worked fine and I didn't lose existing settings like database and debug configurations.

Updated answer thanks to Mostafa Asadi in the comments

Comment: iml file name format is your_project_name.iml